# could all servers execute php scripts?

Tags: php, jakarta-ee, server

I'm sorry for this question, I'm doing a study on the use of `PHP` vs `JavaEE` ..

The server where I'm going to deploy my application ( developed  in `JavaEE` ) contains a JVM , I'm asking if any server can execute PHP scripts . ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any server that has PHP installed can execute PHP scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically any server is capable of executing PHP scripts however the server has to have the PHP binaries installed.  Also in order to serve the PHP scripts to a web client you have to have a server such as Apache or Nginx that will call the php binary to parse the page.

Generally a setup to host a JavaEE application will not be setup to host a PHP based application.  If it is a shared host you are probably out of luck but if it is a personal server, dedicated host or an unmanaged VPS you could install the necessary binaries to serve both on different ports.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I want to know if you know some documentations about what you have said : ` Generally a setup to host a JavaEE application will not be setup to host a PHP based application `

Comment: There is not really documentation for it. Just in general a server is setup to host one type of web application.  However it really depends on what host you are using.  If you have terminal access you can try running php -v to see if php is installed.  If you have sudo access and would like to install a php web application stack [here is a good tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-14-04) for Ubuntu servers.